# WiX Installer placing checkbox below custom bitmap image on dialog

Tags: dialog, wix

I've added the "Launch program" checkbox on the final card of the installer, but for some reason WiX is placing the checkbox below the custom bitmap instead of on top of it with the other text. Can someone point me in the right direction to getting the checkbox directly below the other text instead of below the background image?

I followed the tutorial on this page to add the checkbox: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html

[image]

Comment: No time to look at this right now, but here is a link to a github sample on dialog customization: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXCustomDialog and here is one more with an open log file construct: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXOpenLogFile

Comment: I will check those out @SteinÅsmul. Thank you!

Comment: As far as I recall I did something to tweak the custom dialog I created for the last project (open log file). Please try to compile it and run the setup. You need to set an upgrade guid first. Generate one here: https://www.guidgenerator.com/

Comment: Some more links: https://installdude.com/ (visit the ["Jumpgate"](https://installdude.com/jumpgate.php)). Some links to WiX GUI: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761784/129130), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765526/129130), [**3**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674815/129130) (do visit this one), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160609/129130)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across [this page](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/well-done/) on the WiX toolset docs. Basically, it says that the checkbox with the grey background is a common complaint and there's a workaround mentioned, but not a way to remove the background.

> And a common complaint: no, the checkbox can't have a transparent background. If you have a bitmap in the background, it will be ugly, just like in our example above. The only workaround is to reduce the width of the checkbox to the actual box itself and to place an additional static text (these can be made transparent) adjacent to it.

EDIT (for completeness): It looks like my initial guess on what was going on with the bitmap image wasn't accurate, based on the above-quoted page. Closing this as answered.