# Is there any way I can add custom dialogs in Wix standard dialogs?

Tags: xml, wix, installation, wix3

I've created a WIX installer using the standard dialog Mondo, but between LicenseAgreement dialog and SetupType dialog I want to add my customized dialog containing some information about the user, is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Have a look at WiX [tutorial](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) as well

Comment: [**Another answer you can check out**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690724/wix-custom-dialog-when-previous-version-exists).