# Windows Installer - remove as Administrator

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Good morning, I have a problem with a Wix installer (it is the first time I use wix) it turns out that when I start everything is fine, and it asks me for administrator permissions, in the "install" button it shows me the icon that I will need those permissions

[image: Img 1]

when I click on Install,
I get the windows to notice to provide the permissions. Until there everything is fine. Then I run the installer again, and it gives me three options, Change - Repair- Remove

[image: Img 2]

I click on remove (which also has the icon that needs Admin Privileges),
but it doesn't ask me for Administrator permissions and it executes the uninstall badly, it doesn't delete registry keys and other things.

[image: Img 3]

I need you to always ask me for the permits. Can someone tell me what's going on?
Thanks

Comment: What dialog set are you using?

Comment: I using MaintenanceTypeDlg

Comment: I meant the ***`UIRef`*** element? For example ***`<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />`***.

Comment: Is a Custom dialog, <UIRef Id="UI_Custom" />

Comment: OK, when I test with Mondo I get mostly expected results. The ***Remove*** elevates, but ***Change*** and ***Repair*** does not (regular users can service the existing installation, but not remove it). Do you have the sources in github.com so we can look? You need to look at the Mondo dialog set and its configuration and replicate - I guess. If I were you I would first test using Mondo to verify that it works properly?

Comment: How did you go with this? You have the links to [the dialog sources in WiX github](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib)? More links in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390664/how-does-the-msi-installer-from-wix-decide-what-to-run#comment106859538_60390664).

Comment: Any luck with this? There are many issues to test here beyond the obvious with regards to elevation for non-admin users and AD deployment, but most people never test it. Application packages may work to redesign the MSI to support it.