# How can i add a button to wix installer finish dialog box

Tags: wix

I am currently using WixUI_Minimal dialog set, So, just like optional text (CA_Set_WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT) can we add a button to the finish or exit dialog box on success scenario? I want to open a pdf file on the button click action.

Below is the code of how i am adding a custom text on finish dialog:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
    <CustomAction Id="CA_Set_WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Thank you for installing [ProductName]."/>
    <InstallUISequence>
      <Custom Action="CA_Set_WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" After="FindRelatedProducts">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallUISequence>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this sample: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXOpenLogFile

It will show a check box that you can use to open the MSI log file. The MsiLogging property defined in the source file means that the log file will always be created. If you remove it the check box in the last dialog will be hidden (unless the log is still created by policy).

Here are a couple of other samples:

- ***Custom Dialog Basics***: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXCustomDialog - this sample shows the basic of customizing WiX dialogs. You base yourself off an existing WiX default dialog set and then extend it as necessary. This sample is very basic.
- ***Experimental Dialog***: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXViewLogExperiment - this little experiment uses a spawned dialog to show "something" at the end of the setup. Not too successful, but at least functional for testing and further experimentation. It is essentially an effort to prevent the update problems of normal MSI dialogs.

---

***Links:***

- [On WiX dialogs and MSI GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654935/changing-text-color-to-wix-dialogs/52674815#52674815)
- [Injecting dialogs in WiX dialog sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765526/129130)

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. The links you provided will be helpful if i am implementing a custom dialog box. But i want to add a button in the inbuild dialog box (WixUI_Minimal) of wix (finish screen). Do you know how can i do that?