# Check for a file existence in WIX SEtup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wix

I am creating a Setup for my .Net Application using WIX.
I want to check the existence of a file before installing my WIX SET UP as a Dependency.
If that file not exist then a message should be displayed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To check for the existence of a file you can use the `FileSearch`-element in combination with the `DirectorySearch`-element. For an example you can take a look at [How To: Check the Version Number of a File During Installation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/check_the_version_number.html) (you don't have to use the version part for your needs).

For displaying the dialog you can create your own `SpawnDialog` like described [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/interactions). Another alternative would be to add the text as property to the Welcome-dialog and set the property based on your findings. Still another way would be to include a second Welcome-dialog and then invoke the needed one as described in [this stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734551/wix-show-custom-dialog-if-previous-version-found).